# How can I make sure Selenium always recognizes my HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have made a program that clicks on various Instagram prompts, and I've used CSS_SELECTOR to recognize these buttons and to click on them. The problem is, it only works sometimes. In these cases

```
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.bIiDR"))).click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click()
```

CSS_SELECTOR works fine, but in this case

```
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF"))).click()
```

It doesn't work. I think the reason for this is that the HTML tag changes every time I load up my page. But what can I do for the program to always recognize the buttons? I know there are different ways that Selenium can recognize the button that I want to click, but are there any that work all the time?

Comment: You need to share HTML code for `sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF`, this css looks brittle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error! Turns out I forgot to put a . before `.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF`